# Update documents on another core after every update

Tags: solr, faceted-search

Is it possible to configure Solr to update aggregated data into another core, every time a new doc is added.

### Example

Lets say you have a `events` core and a `aggregate` core.
Every time a new event is added in the `events` core, I want the `aggregate` core to update some information for each event type.

I understand that this can be done using facets, but I want to understand if its possible to pre-aggregate data to another core or even same core.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to perform some action every time a doc is added, you have the [postcommit hook](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig) available (triggered upon a commit, not update, but will work for you I think).

With that, you can run some java/sh/whatever piece of code that by using facets/streaming expressions/normal queries can aggregate the data and insert it into the other collection.